# Pictures of quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

There are at least two pictures of quantum mechanics - Schrödinger's and Heisenberg's. Both are equivalent. Doesn't it mean that both are just models of reality and not the reality itself?

I mean, how two different things can be equally correct unless they are same at a deeper level?

Could it be that state kets and operators are the same thing at a deeper level (I know its silly)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics   for an overview of the (greater  than two) interpretations

Comment: Is there any case in which you would consider a physical theory to be "reality itself" instead of "just a model of reality"?

Comment: To speak about the *reality* of any physical system are we not communicating in terms of some accepted model? What George Box said, something like "All models are wrong ... but some are useful" captures the essence. Sometimes, some of us lose sight and believe our models *are* reality

Comment: @JohnForkosh one of these days I'm going to order all of Jammer's books from Dover - and read!  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Pick a point in space. If you use one coordinate system, the position of that point might be (4, -94, 23). If you use another coordinate system, the point might be at (-2, 3, -1). It's the same point in any case. The Schrodinger and Heisenberg pictures are much like this: two different mathematical representations of the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a philosophy of science question as it is concerned with an ontological question, "what is reality," moreso than a scientific question, "what are useful models that help us explain and predict the phenomena that we see?".

The truth is, this is not the first case where two completely different viewpoints are mathematically equivalent, nor is it the last. For the earliest example that I know of, the viewpoints that the Earth orbits the Sun and that the Sun orbits the Earth are revealed, in Newtonian mechanics, to be mathematically equivalent. Every college physics student who gets at least to a junior undergraduate level, and potentially much earlier, derives that you can switch into a rotating reference frame by simply adding two force terms, one called "centrifugal" and one called "Coriolis". The only thing that the heliocentric folks added was an early form of Fourier decomposition, with which the motions of planets are described via "epicycles." But they're mathematically equivalent.

Viewing signals in the time-domain vs. the frequency-domain is another question of perspective; the Fourier transform proves that they are equivalent.

Classical mechanics has at least three valid perspectives with different ontologies: Newtonian mechanics, Lagrangian mechanics, and Hamiltonian mechanics. They're mathematically equivalent. Noether's theorem pointed out that you could view conservation laws like conservation-of-energy as secretly being symmetries in the laws of physics like invariance-under-time-translation.

Classical electromagnetism was phrased in Newtonian terms but it becomes much more pretty and useful once you have access to special relativity, but early arguments from Lorentz and others suggested that you didn't necessarily need relativity; length contraction for example can be explained as the standard electromagnetic equations applying to these electromagnetic orbits of electrons: on this account the spaceship genuinely and objectively contracts but the people on-board merely don't notice it because their rulers have also contracted as have the electromagnetic processes that keep them alive.

And then it turns out that this whole "spacetime" idea that grounds relativity (both special and general) with four-vector fields as tangent spaces on a manifold, can be instead square-rooted and described with two-spinor fields (equivalently quaternion fields). Penrose discovered yet another approach in the 1970s, describing spacetime as "twistor space".

For the most recent case that I know of, string theory often deals with the AdS/CFT correspondence where a quantum field theory in our happy CFT world is translated to a field theory in this strange higher-dimensional anti-de-Sitter space.

So yes: Quantum theory only predicts averages $\langle A \rangle$ and gives two main "pictures" (and an infinity of "interaction pictures" in between!) for how these vary in time: Schrodinger's $\langle A \rangle = \langle \psi(t) | \hat A | \psi(t) \rangle$ and Heisenberg's $\langle A \rangle = \langle \psi | \hat A(t) | \psi \rangle.$ To these we should also add the state matrix formalism, $\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$ with $\langle A \rangle = \operatorname{Tr} (\rho \hat A),$ and the work that Feynman, Tomonaga, and Schwinger won the Nobel Prize for where we view these probability-amplitudes instead through some action-integral formalism. We should also muse about the ontological implications of "second quantization" frameworks and the emergence of quantum field theory.

But the point is that while these deep mathematical equivalences are very useful for getting a different perspective on something, they limit our ability to say useful ontological things. These distinctions can only be resolved by finding more useful theories that help us better model the world at more and more fundamental levels; no other resolution exists because they are mathematically equivalent and therefore models in one predict the exact same things as models in another.

Ultimately the ontological speculation is not physics. Physicists can adopt whichever ontology happens to meet their needs at the time because we're not necessarily out to discover some profound philosophical truth: we're just out to explain why these things are, using models that other physicists (and hopefully eventually the lay public) will understand and be able to use to model their own topics of interest.

Answer (score -4):

There are more than just those two. There is also certainly debate on whether they should be called "interpretations". But in any case all interpretations of QM are just attempts to bring it into the classical world so we can "understand" it classically, yet the classical world is only what statistically emerges from QM. So it can't be brought into the classical world. Its like the difference between the attributes of a swarm of bees seen from a distance (our classical view) and a single bee (QM), and trying to describe the bee in terms of the attributes of a swarm. We'll try to define it as a translucent fluid blob that makes a rushing sound and can't harm you, rather than an opaque buzzing object that *can* harm you, which (hypothetically) we have never seen the likes of.

Comment: Hi I did not d/v your answer, but I think this line might be unhelpful **But in any case all interpretations of QM are just attempts to bring it into the classical world so we can "understand" it classically**.  I think lots of people using QM don't even try to put a classical meaning to it, they just acccept it, either as the "real" world or pragmatically and mathemathically, without needing a classical viewpoint to work with it.